# JavaFX: NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/mail/internet/AddressException when creating Jar

Tags: java, javafx, jakarta-mail

I am trying to add the ability to send emails via my javafx application through the Jakarta mail dependency. It runs perfectly fine in the IDE and I am able to send emails while testing but once I build my artifacts to an executable jar and attempt to run the executable jar, I get the following error stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/mail/internet/AddressException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3429)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3634)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2810)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:939)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:981)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:755)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2845)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2641)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2555)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2523)
        at com.Sapplication.Controllers.DashControllerAdmin.initPanes(DashControllerAdmin.java:114)
        at com.Sapplication.Controllers.DashControllerAdmin.initialize(DashControllerAdmin.java:77)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2662)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2555)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2523)
        at com.Sapplication.StageControllers.CreateStage.createStage(CreateStage.java:23)
        at com.Sapplication.Controllers.LoginController.btnSignIn(LoginController.java:203)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.mail.internet.AddressException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 56 more
```

**This is the code in my program: **

```
    Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        }
    };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(PROPERTIES, authenticator);
    session.setDebug(debug);

    try {

        // create a message with headers
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // create message body
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        for (String message : messages) {
            MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
            mbp.setText(message, "us-ascii");
            mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
        }
        msg.setContent(mp);

        // send the message
        Transport.send(msg);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Email Sent Successfully!");
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}`
```

If I comment out the code and rebuild my artifacts the program runs just fine!

I have gone through multiple forums of people having the same issue and have followed a few suggestions
1.) I added both the Jakarta mail dependency and the Jakarta activation dependency to my POM

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

2.) I've also gone into Project structure -> Libraries & Project structure -> Modules and made sure that both Maven: com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:2.0.1 and Maven: com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:2.0.1 are showing up. I've also tried deleting the maven version and downloading the jars and adding the jars directly  as well as keeping the maven version and installing the jars but both ways are still causing the same error upon trying to run the program after building the jar.

3.) A few answers said to add it to my VM options and These are my current VM options:

`--module-path`

`"C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib"`

`--add-modules`

`javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,jakarta.activation,jakarta.mail`

`--add-exports`

`javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=ALL-UNNAMED`

A few more details:

IDE: IntellJ
SDK: OpenJDK 19.0.2

If anyone has any idea why I'm still getting the error, I would really appreciate the help thank you! (Sorry for any formatting issues, this is my first time asking a question on here!)

Edit:
Command in CMD:

```
java -jar "C:\Users\Main PC\Desktop\SApplication.jar"
```

I am able to run the application without the jakarta.mail dependency fine using this method!

To create the excutable jar: I go to Build -> build artifacts -> builds to an executable jar in the out folder of the project. I use the jar with jdeploy later to manage updates.

Edit: Modules in the project.
[image: Here is the modules in the project]

Comment: Aside: I don't recommend using `JOptionPane` in a JavaFX application.  [JavaFX has (for ten years) had dialogs you can use instead of relying on Swing](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/).

Comment: Note: from the [jakarta mail site](https://jakartaee.github.io/mail-api/README-JakartaMail) -> "To break tight integration between Jakarta Mail Specification API and the implementation, sources of the implementation were moved to the new project - [Eclipse Angus](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/angus-mail) - and further development continues there. Eclipse Angus is the direct successor of JavaMail/JakartaMail."

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` means the class cannot be found by a class loader. In standard cases, that means the class is not on the `--class-path` or `--module-path`. You say it works in your IDE, but that's because you are (presumably) running it via Maven and Maven will put dependencies on the class-path/module-path for you. How are you ensuring Jakarta Mail is being placed on the class-path/module-path when executing your executable JAR file?

Comment: Aside: from the stack trace, JavaFX is being loaded from the classpath rather than the module path.  You can see that because the classes in the stack trace prefixed by a module name e.g. `java.base/` are loaded from the module path, but those which have no module prefix (such as the JavaFX classes) are not being loaded from the module path.

Comment: Edit the question, add the complete command you use to run your application to it as text, formatted as code.   Also provide info on how you created an "executable jar" and what is in it.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions! I am going to try Eclipse Angus first. As for the class path, that was one of the first suggestions from previous forums on this issue so I double checked online and for intellj, the options to ensure the class was on the module path or the  class path was to go the project structure and manually adding the the jars which I did do to no avail! I can look again to see if maybe I'm missing something but that's what most recommended for that issue

Comment: You are using Maven, you should not have to "manually" add jars anywhere.  Maven (and the Idea integration) should do that for you.  If you are manually adding jars, you are incorrectly using the tools.  Once the application is built, both Idea and Maven are irrelevant. Then all you are doing is using the `java` tool, instructions for which are in the [java man page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html#standard-options-for-java).

Comment: Specifically for the option you use, `-jar` -> "When you use -jar, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored."  So, if you use that option, the jar file is the classpath where app classes are found and other sources of the classes or custom module path info is irrelevant.  If the classes aren't in the jar, they can't be found.  If you tried to make the application modular, with a module info, it will be ignored.  If the file `jakarta.mail.internet.AddressException` is not in your jar, it won't be found. (use `jar tvf <jarfile>` to test)

Comment: The previous answers were also using Maven but still suggested manually adding the jars so I tried it but I removed the manually added jars and it was still not working. Within the modules, I do see the dependencies correctly showing up but still an error! I will edit and add a screen shot of the modules.

Comment: The "previous answers" you refer to are wrong or perhaps taken out of context.  It would be best to link to relevant references to provide context and credit (or apportioned blame ;-).

Comment: *"To create the excutable jar: I go to Build -> build artifacts -> builds to an executable jar"* -> don't do that.  Idea (as of early 2024) does not know how to accurately create executable jars for JavaFX applications.  Instead [use your build tool (Maven) to create the jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing) (or some other package type, e.g. jlink zip, or jpackage installer).   Further info on packaging JavaFX applications (an unfortunately complex discussion) is in the [javafx tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).